# Unable to migrate from httpSecurity.authorizeRequests to Authorizehttprequests in spring security

Tags: authentication, spring-security, authorization

I am trying to migrate to spring security 5.8.3 from Spring security 5.7.x. httpSecurity.authorizeRequests() has been deprecated and the javadocs suggests to use httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests() instead. But this direct replacement doesnt seem to work for me. Am getting 403 forbidden error. I read the official documentation but am not able to figure out what exactly i am missing. PS i am very new to spring security and spring itself in general.

My code:

```
@Bean

public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception

{

log.atInfo().log("Configuring security for rest api using Avm based authentication");

configureCommonRestApiAspects(httpSecurity);

configureCommonAuthenticationAspects(httpSecurity);

configureCommonAuthAspects(httpSecurity, new AvmJwtAuthenticationFilter(), unAuthorizedEntryPoint);

return httpSecurity.build();

}


static void configureCommonRestApiAspects(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception

{

httpSecurity.requestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/rest/**"));

httpSecurity.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS); // Disable session management completely

httpSecurity.csrf().disable(); 

httpSecurity.cors();

}

 

static void configureCommonAuthenticationAspects(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception

{
httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated(); // All calls require authentication
// I am changing the above line to this:
httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().authenticated(); // All calls require authentication

}

 

static void configureCommonAuthAspects(HttpSecurity httpSecurity, Filter authenticationFilter, AuthenticationEntryPoint unAuthorizedEntryPoint) throws Exception

{

httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter, AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class); // This filter prepares the authentication object based on the JWT token

httpSecurity.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unAuthorizedEntryPoint); // Return HTTP 401 instead of the default 403

}
```